# moving through variables in matrix with recursion

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write a function which got a kind of a matrix - a list that consists of sub-lists
So I want to go through all the matrix members and print them out. Only in recursion!
But I dont know how to create a good "stop conditions" for my function.
So I get more numbers than I wanted.

```
def mission(mat):    

def move(mat, i=0, j=0 ,k=0):
    print(mat[i][j])
    if j<(len(mat[0])-1):
        move(mat,i,j+1)
    if i<(len(mat)-1):
        move(mat,i+1,0)
    
    

move(mat)


mat = [[1, 0, 0, 3, 0],
[0, 0, 2, 3, 0],
[2, 0, 0, 2, 0],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3]]        
mission(mat)
```

*edit
I got another question - is there a way to decrease 2 list that looks like the mat function i did here (with the same length - just different numbers)
without using numpy or for ?

Comment: Did you accidentally change your code when you pasted it? There's no indented block under `mission(mat)`. Does it just call `move`? When recursing through the 2d matrix, is there a specific ordering you want to go in, or just increment the indexes until you finish?

Comment: I think he did not meant to include the function `mission()` and did not meant to call it either. As such, for testing purposes. you should remove both of these lines, and move the matrix initialization above the statement: `move(mat)`.

Comment: I ran his code and it looks like he wants to print each item in the sublists in the order in which they appear, and moving to the next list. However, he is ending up printing the whole matrix multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

as for the `move` function, simply change the 2nd `if` to `elif`

```
def move(mat, i=0, j=0):
    print(mat[i][j])
    if j<(len(mat[0])-1):
        move(mat,i,j+1)
    elif i<(len(mat)-1):
        move(mat,i+1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test for end condition on function start, and check if you have already crossed the last item in the last sublist. If so, you `return`.

```
if(i == len(mat) - 1 and j == len(mat[0]) - 1):
    return
```

Then, you check whether you are at the last item in your current sublist, and if so, increment the sublist index `i` and set the item index back to `0`.

```
if(j == len(mat[0]) - 1):
    i += 1
    j = 0
```

If you are neither at the end of the whole 2d matrix (list), nor the end of any sublist, you just need to increment the item index `j`.

```
else:
    j += 1
```

Then, you can safely call your function recursively. The whole code ends up looking like this.

```
def move(mat, i=0, j=0):
    print(mat[i][j])
    if(i == len(mat) - 1 and j == len(mat[0]) - 1):
        return
    if(j == len(mat[0]) - 1):
        i += 1
        j = 0
    else:
        j += 1

    move(mat, i, j)


mat = [[1, 0, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 3, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 3]]

move(mat)
```

**Output:**:

```
1
0
0
3
0
0
0
2
3
0
2
0
0
2
0
0
1
2
3
3
```